# Calculating the mean values between every row inside a range

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of size 700x20. My data are pixel intensity coordinates for specific locations on an image, where i have 14 people where each has 50 images. I am trying to perform dimensionality reduction and for such task one of the steps require me to calculate the mean between each class, where  i have two classes. In my dataframe in every 50th row are the features that belongs to a class, therefore i'd have from 0 to 50 features for class A, 51 to 100  features for class B, 101-150 for class A, 151-200 for class B and so on.

What i want to do is calculate the mean for every nth given row, from N to M and calculate the mean value. Here's a link for the dataframe for better visualization of the problem: [Dataframe pickle file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/tejt4wh8izn3vmd/my_dataframe_file/file)

What i tried was ordering the the dataframe and calculate separately but it didn't work, it calculated the mean for every row and grouped them in 14 different classes.

```
class_feature_means = pd.DataFrame(columns=target_names)
for c, rows in df.groupby('class'):
    class_feature_means[c] = rows.mean()
class_feature_means
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
my_array = np.asarray([[31, 25, 17, 62],
 [31, 26, 19, 59,],
 [31, 23, 17, 67,],
 [31, 23, 19, 67,],
 [31, 28, 17, 65,],
 [32, 26, 19, 62,],
 [32, 26, 17, 66,],
 [30, 24, 17, 68],
 [29, 24, 17, 68],
 [33, 24, 17, 68],
 [32, 52, 16, 68],
 [29, 24, 17, 68],
 [33, 24, 17, 68],
 [32, 52, 16, 68],
 [29, 24, 17, 68],
 [33, 24, 17, 68],
 [32, 52, 16, 68],
 [30, 25, 16, 97]])


my_array = my_array.reshape(18, 4)

my_array = my_array.reshape(18, 4)
indices = sorted(list(range(0,int(my_array.shape[0]/3)))*3)
class_dict = dict(zip(range(0,int((my_array.shape[0]/3))), string.ascii_uppercase))
target_names = ["Index_" + c for c in class_dict.values()]
pixel_index = [1, 2, 3, 4]


X = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns= pixel_index)
y = pd.Categorical.from_codes(indices,target_names)
df = X.join(pd.Series(y,name='class'))


df
```

Basically what i want to do is **group into a unique class** A, C, E, take their sum and divide by 3, therefore achieving mean value for class A or lets call it class 0.
Then, **group into a unique class** B, D, F, take their sum and divide by 3, therefore achieving mean value for class B, or class 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create helper array with inteegr division and modulo for groups and pass to groupby for aggregate `sum`, last divide:

```
N = 3
arr = np.arange(len(df)) // N % 2
print (arr)
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]

df = df.groupby(arr).sum() / N
print (df)
           1          2          3           4
0  92.666667  82.666667  51.333333  198.000000
1  94.333333  92.666667  51.333333  210.333333
```

Comment: It's doing the same thing i did though, which is not correct. Basically, i'd like to sum rows from 0-50, 150-200, 250-300, 350-400, 450-500, 550-600, 650-700, sum these rows and divide them by 7, then that'll be the average for class A, then i can just repeat the process for class B but for the other values

Comment: @JohnJones - so need change `mean` to `sum` and divide by `7` ? How is possible verify correctness output data?

Comment: The classes are wrong as a result of my attempt which is my code, that's why i am trying to take the mean that way. Changing it to sum, it won't guarantee correctness, that's why i asked how to sum from row 50 to 100 for instance for 7 different rows

Comment: @JohnJones - so need change `s = np.arange(len(df)) // N` ?

Comment: Why? i tried implementing your solution, it doesn't calculate means

Comment: @JohnJones - Then it seems I dont understand what need, sorry. Maybe because missing [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here e.g. 2 columns, 10-12 rows and expected output for verify solution. Then N should be 3 in sample data

Comment: alright i have edited the code with the minimal, complete and reproducible code. It should explain better what i am trying to do exactly, i am sorry for the poor example previously

Comment: @JohnJones - Thank you. For me is not clear `Basically what i want to do is group into a unique class A, C, E, take their sum and divide by 3,` - it means 1 group is 3rows, omit 3 rows, 3 rows, omit 3rows...to end of DataFrame? And second group is from omited rows? So always output is 2 groups? How looks expected output DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, imagine this: every 3 rows is yes and the next 3 rows are no, i want to sum all the yes's rows and no's rows and take average